# Show/Hide Editor Not Responding

Tags: xml, wysiwyg, edit-order, tinymce

I have tried to look for previous solution and couldn't find any relevant topics. So I guess I should post a new question here. We are trying to toggle the WYSIWYG editor (Which is turned by default) and it is not responding. I inspected the element and it shows these errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: tinyMceWysiwygSetup is not a constructor
```

I tried to compare the tiny_mce folder under the js directory with another working magento website. Their respective sum is the same so I think the problem doesn't occur at this place.

Any clue or idea to resolve this issue?

Thank you very much in advance!

[image: WYSIWYG Error]

Comment: UPDATE: We have tried to troubleshoot the problem and it seems that the error lies in one of the js files. The problem is solved when we turned off the "Merge Javascript" setting. Currently, we are trying to fix that by looking into the separate js files and hopefully something will turn out in the end.

Comment: Have you tried different web browsers?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I enabled and disabled wysiwyg by default is System -> Configuration -> Content Management, then cleared cache and it was solved. Nothing special

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am afraid our problem is serious than this. We have tried to toggle the WYSIWYG editor through Configurations but the problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your should check request js files in browser. It should have `tinymce_setup` or `tinymce_src` i don't remember correct name.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. So this issue was solved after i reindexed all indexer and i also flushed the cache

So try after reindexing and flushing cache.